# Change Font Size in Excel Table

Tags: excel, fonts, size, typeface

I have a table, "Schedule", and I want the check the table column, "Number". If "Number" in a row is blank I want to change the cell for that row in the column "Name" to be font size 11 non-bold but if "Number" isn't blank I want to change "Name" to font size 12 bold.

I'm not sure how to do this. I also have some 60,000 cells and growing so it needs to do as little work as possible so it stays as fast as possible.

I'll edit this since I added typeface in the question and not in the subject. I was planning on doing this with VBA because I can't do font size in conditional.

Comment: Sounds like you could do this with conditional formatting

Comment: Only partially, unfortunately. Would love to know why conditional formatting can't change font size.

Answer (score 1):

With conditional formatting, you can set the font to bold (also change text colour and cell background colour). Unfortunately it can't change font size.

Starting with this table, where `Number` is column `C`:

[image: starting table, columns Name, Year of birth, Number, all plain formatted]

You can add conditional formatting with "Use a formula..." for the rule, and set that formula to `=ISBLANK(@$C:$C)`.

(Alternatively you could give a relevant name to the appropriate column and use the column name instead: `=ISBLANK(@registration_number)`)

[image: screenshot of the above]

Then click `Format` and apply Bold style (and/or any highlighting colours).

Then in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager(Conditional Formatting -> Manage rules), change `Applies to` to cover your table:

[image: screenshot of above]

Rows where `Number` is blank are now bold.

[image]

---

To change font size automatically within Excel, this is only possible with Visual Basic.

You could however periodically filter the table for rows where `Number` is blank and manually set the font size / style.

Comment: ... but you can't change the font size with conditional formatting, right?

Comment: Nope. OP asks "Font size" in title but "Font size and make bold" in the question body so this is a partial answer without reaching for VBA.